# How adding brackets in laravel query?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

My query laravel is like this :

```
$customer = Customer::where('full_name', 'iLIKE', '%'.$param['keyword'].'%')
                                ->orWhere('mobile', 'iLIKE', '%'.$param['keyword'].'%')
                                ->orWhere('phone', 'iLIKE', '%'.$param['keyword'].'%')
                                ->where('published','1')
                                ->where('customer_status','N')
                                ->orderBy('full_name', 'ASC')->get();
```

If I print regular query use this :

```
DB::listen(function($sql, $bindings, $time) {
            \Log::info($sql);
            \Log::info(print_r($bindings,1));
            \Log::info($time);
        });
```

The result :

```
select * from "ss_customer" 
where "full_name" iLIKE '%ronaldo%' or "mobile" iLIKE '%ronaldo%' or "phone" iLIKE '%ronaldo%' and "published" = 1 and "customer_status" = 'N' 
order by "full_name" asc
```

I would like to add brackets so the query becomes like this :

```
select * from "ss_customer" 
where ("full_name" iLIKE '%ronaldo%' or "mobile" iLIKE '%ronaldo%' or "phone" iLIKE '%ronaldo%') and "published" = 1 and "customer_status" = 'N' 
order by "full_name" asc
```

How to add brackets in laravel query?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy, just pass your query as a closure

```
       $customer = Customer::where(function($query) use ($param) {
        $query->where('full_name', 'iLIKE', '%'.$param['keyword'].'%')
                ->orWhere('mobile', 'iLIKE', '%'.$param['keyword'].'%')
                ->orWhere('phone', 'iLIKE', '%'.$param['keyword'].'%');
    })->where('published','1')
        ->where('customer_status','N')
        ->orderBy('full_name', 'ASC')->get();
```