# Laravel 5.3 adding brackets to eloquent query that has orWhere clause and AND condition

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I am obviously new to laravel, i am trying to build this query

```
select * from `users` where (`is_enumerator` is not null) and (`firstname` LIKE '%nai%' or `email` LIKE '%nai%' or `id` LIKE '%nai%' or `lastname` LIKE '%nai%' or `county` LIKE '%nai%' or `ward` LIKE '%nai%')
```

but this is what i'm getting

```
select * from `users` where (`is_enumerator` is not null) and `firstname` LIKE '%nai%' or `email` LIKE '%nai%' or `id` LIKE '%nai%' or `lastname` LIKE '%nai%' or `county` LIKE '%nai%' or `ward` LIKE '%nai%'
```

when using this eloquent query

**Edit**  $query = Input::get('search-user'); //from the search box

```
    if($query !='') {
$user = User::where(function ($query) {
            $query->whereNotNull('is_enumerator');

        })->where('firstname', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
                ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
                ->orWhere('id', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
                ->orWhere('lastname', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
                ->orWhere('county', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
                ->orWhere('ward', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
            ->get();
```

}

The brackets change the query completely, without them some users show up with the results from the search query. I have tried this link [adding brackets in laravel query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34589028/how-adding-brackets-in-laravel-query#34589106) but it throws and error "builder cannot be converted to string error". I am sure its very simple i just cant find it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've actually done the right thing, just in reverse.

Right now, your query reads

```
WHERE (is_enumerator IS NOT NULL)
AND firstname LIKE '%...%'
AND email LIKE '%...%'
... and so on
```

So you put the first query in a function closure, when it should really be the second. :) Something like this.

```
$user = User::where(function ($q) use ($query) {
        $q->where('firstname', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
          ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
          ->orWhere('id', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
          ->orWhere('lastname', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
          ->orWhere('county', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
          ->orWhere('ward', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%');
    })
    ->whereNotNull('is_enumerator')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks but using your correction gives me this error `Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string` .

Comment: Ah, sorry - I forgot to pass the query variable to the closure. Please see the updated version.

Comment: This solved my problem!, thank you for your time my good man.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this : `User::where(function ($query) use ($variable){..`

With the  `use ($variable)` you are able to define a variabel to be used inside your query.

***variable** is the variable you want to use

Comment: thank you for your answer i have edited the question to show that i dont have any other variable other than the $query variable that i get from the search box.